# Docker Running In Cloud Run Jobs Throws ClassNotFoundException, Runs Fine On Docker Desktop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm building a java application to run on a schedule using Cloud Run Jobs. This application has a main method that is called to perform its task. I am packaging this up into a docker container that runs successfully on my local machine using Docker Desktop. I then tag and push the image to Artifact Registry. I then select the image when setting up a new Cloud Run Jobs Instance and it fails. It is failing and exiting with an error. The logs read as this:

> 2022-09-06T04:03:30.441244ZError: Could not find or load main class
> one.studio.Main Default 2022-09-06T04:03:30.441270ZCaused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: one.studio.Main Warning
> 2022-09-06T04:03:30.449143ZContainer called exit(1).

This really confuses me about everything I've been learning about Docker, in that I thought the application is able to execute the same on each machine. I'm not really sure what to include for this, as I don't see what would have an effect on this.

```
Dockerfile
```

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17

COPY target/classes/ /tmp

WORKDIR /tmp

ADD ./lib/mysql-socket-factory-1.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar lib/
ADD ./lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar lib/
ADD ./lib/twilio-9.0.0-rc.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar lib/
ADD ./lib/my-erp-359002-2816e69f4a8a.json /tmp/lib/my-erp-359002-2816e69f4a8a.json

ENV CLASSPATH=lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:${CLASSPATH}
ENV CLASSPATH=lib/mysql-socket-factory-1.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:${CLASSPATH}
ENV CLASSPATH=lib/twilio-9.0.0-rc.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar:${CLASSPATH}
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/tmp/lib/my-erp-359002-2816e69f4a8a.json"

CMD java one.studio.Main
```

```
docker-compose.yml
```

```
version: "3"
services:
  web-app:
    build: .
```

[My Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydbsY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing directory from /tmp to /app. Dockerfile has been updated as follows:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17

COPY target/classes/ /app

WORKDIR /app

ADD ./lib/mysql-socket-factory-1.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar lib/
ADD ./lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar lib/
ADD ./lib/twilio-9.0.0-rc.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar lib/
ADD ./lib/my-erp-359002-2816e69f4a8a.json /lib/my-erp-359002-2816e69f4a8a.json

ENV CLASSPATH=lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:${CLASSPATH}
ENV CLASSPATH=lib/mysql-socket-factory-1.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:${CLASSPATH}
ENV CLASSPATH=lib/twilio-9.0.0-rc.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar:${CLASSPATH}
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/lib/my-erp-359002-2816e69f4a8a.json"

CMD ["java", "one.studio.Main"]
```